# How long does Lentivirus take to express in vivo mouse neurons?

Tags: neuroscience, lab-techniques, virology

Does anyone know how long it takes for a standard Lentivirus vector to express its genes (under a strong promoter such as CAG, CB7, etc.), after injection into the brain of a mouse?

By hearsay I think it's 2 weeks for full expression, is that true?

Comment: i also heard that it takes a week. but you should frame your question better. this looks like a survey

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on what you are expressing (such as how stable it is), and where you need it (soma vs dendrites vs axons, and whether it is trafficked actively in the cell).

For optogenetic constructs, our lab has typically seen near-peak expression around 3 weeks, though expression may be suitable earlier, and toxic later.